# passing multiple values to switch separating the values by commas

Tags: c, switch-statement

Can I pass multiple values to the switch case statement separating different values by commas ? what would the expression evaluate to? If no error occurs, which of the multiple values would the compiler evaluate the switch with ? Keeping in mind the low precedence of the comma operator? say for instance i write the code as follows:

```
int m=10;
switch(m, m*2)
{
     case 10: printf("\n case 10");
     case 20: printf("\n case 20");
     case 30: printf("\n case 30");
     default: printf("\n no case");
 }
```

Comment: note that in your code if a case matches `m*2` all subsequent cases will be executed. `break` is often used to prevent that but maybe you don't want that

Comment: don't forget to add "break;" statements between cases.

Answer (score 6):

The comma operator evaluates all the expressions and returns the value of the rightmost one.  (It doesn't make any difference that you're using it in a `switch`.)

Your example is exactly the same as `switch (m*2)`, but if any of the preceding expressions had side effects, those side effect would be applied before the `switch` statement was executed.

Comment: You should mention that the operator executes all expressions before returning; so it can make sens to use it in a switch

Comment: Can u please explain what evaluating all expressions mean ? does this imply that it will evaluate all the cases which match with the values inside the braces, or just the rightmost value would me taken for matching?

Comment: @user2693690: Only the rightmost value will be passed into the switch statement.  When I say "evaluates all the expressions" I mean that if you said something like `switch (f(), ++m, m)` then function `f` would be called, `m` would be incremented, and then the `switch` statement would be executed with the (incremented) value of `m`.  (This stuff is well-defined and easy to experiment with - try it with your compiler!)